# problem send data from renderer to new modal window in electron js

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules

I have started to learn Electron JS platform
In a project that I have defined for myself, I have two windows
The second window opens as a modal
I have a problem to send data from the first window to the second window

I have used the following method
view.js

```
function openPrint() {
    let win2 = new remote.BrowserWindow({
        parent: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
        modal: true,
        webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    })

    var theUrl = 'file://' + __dirname + '/printer.html'
    //console.log('url', theUrl);

    win2.loadURL(theUrl);
    const remoteMain = remote.require("@electron/remote/main");
    remoteMain.enable(win2.webContents);
    ipcRenderer.send('print-data',"test data")
    }
  
  


  var myprint = document.getElementById('print-file'); 
  myprint.addEventListener('click',openPrint)
```

and

```
const remote = require('@electron/remote');


document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', test)
//console.log('tests')

    remote.getCurrentWindow().getParentWindow().on('print-data',(evt,arg)=>{
        console.log(arg)
    });
```

But I didn't succeed... The opposite of this method is possible !!!
That means I can send data from the second window to the first window!!!

I tried these changes too, but it didn't work !!!

```
    win2.loadURL(theUrl);
    const remoteMain = remote.require("@electron/remote/main");
    remoteMain.enable(win2.webContents);

    win2.once("ready-to-show", () => {
        ipcRenderer.send('print-data','test data')
    });
```

Comment: [IPC Pattern 4: Renderer to renderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-4-renderer-to-renderer). And use a preload, not `remote`.

Comment: @Arkellys I am able to send messages from the second window to the first window, but the opposite direction is not possible...

Comment: It's possible, read the docs.